# Log checkpointer in java

Tags: java, logging

I currently have a web service that stores a mapping of keys to some values, I managed to create a background logging system of the commands received by the web service. Now I have to implement a check pointer that will store the log into a file, I`ve implemented it as an extension to Timer Task. So I am thinking that I may be able to use a timer to schedule the check pointer do the task every 20 min or so. My problem is that besides calling the check pointer I have to test if any call to the service is still being processed , wait for it to finish, and then block the webservice untill I send a resume command, a quiesce method.

```
public class MyCheckpointer extends TimerTask implements Checkpointer {

ObjectOutputStream out; 
FileOutputStream file;
MyLogger log;

public MyCheckpointer(MyLogger l)
{
    File log_txt = new File("./log.txt");
    try {
        this.file = new FileOutputStream(log_txt);
        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.file);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.log = l;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.writeLog();
}

private void writeLog()
{
    ArrayList<LogRecord> l = this.log.getArray();
    Iterator<LogRecord> e = l.iterator();
    do
    {
        try {
            out.writeObject(e.next());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }while(e.hasNext());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web service implementation and the MyCheckpointer class could share a synchronization object. For example java.util.concurrent.Lock:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

then both of them should call:

```
lock.lock();
service the command and log/write logs to file
lock.unlock();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fits your use case wholly, but I would advice using a logging framework that supports asynchrous logging instead of rolling your own. For example, log4j provides an async appender: http://www.slf4j.org/nlog4j/api/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to mention that this is done for an school assignment so I need to implement each part by hand.